# "Binary operator > cannot be applied to two Float operands" error

Tags: swift2

I have a conditional that looks like:

```
if sqrtf(powf(startTouch.x - (touches.first as! UITouch).locationInView(self.view).y, 2) + powf(startTouch.y-(touches.first as! UITouch).locationInView(self.view).y, 2)) > dragThreshold as! Float {
        self.drag = false;
}
```

I am getting an error that says `Binary operator > cannot be applied to two Float operands`. I cannot understand why I can't check if a float is greater than another float. What is this error trying to tell me?

Comment: The members of a `CGPoint` are of type `CGFloat`, and assuming you are on a 64-bit architecture the native type used to store a `CGFloat` is `Double` - perhaps try treating those calculated values as `Double`s (use `sqrt()` and `pow()` instead of the `Float` versions)... and what type is `dragThreshold` ?

Comment: @fqdn `dragThreshold` is an Integer. I'll try using doubles with the methods that use them.

Comment: @fqdn This worked, thanks a million!

Comment: you got it! I'll promote my comment to an answer, if you wouldn't mind accepting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The members of a `CGPoint` are of type `CGFloat`, and assuming you are on a 64-bit architecture the native type used to store a `CGFloat` is `Double` - try treating those calculated values as `Double`s (use `sqrt()` and `pow()` instead of the `Float` versions)... using `dragThreshold` as a `Double` as well

Answer (score 1):

Using latest Xcode 7 beta 4 and SpriteKit's function `override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` I did break this big chunk to smaller ones like this:

```
let dragThreshold: Int = 1
let startTouch = CGPointZero
let pow1 = powf(Float(startTouch.x - touches!.first!.locationInView(self.view).y), 2.0)
let pow2 = powf(Float(startTouch.y-touches!.first!.locationInView(self.view).y), 2.0)
let sq = sqrtf(pow1 + pow2)

if sq > Float(dragThreshold) {
    self.drag = false;
}
```

This works. Basically added more conversions for `powf` arguments, changed 2 to 2.0

General advice - if you get some strange errors, try to break down your expression into smaller ones to isolate issue.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this works, but I found converting arguments to doubles better with a nice explanation from fqdn.